# 'yarn' error on a Macbook with M1 chip. bash: yarn: command not found

Tags: reactjs, bash, yarnpkg, apple-m1, macos-monterey

Macbook pro M1 2020 macOS monterey

I am creating a website using react in VScode.
I am creating it using create-react-app. To execute this, after installing 'yarn', 'yarn start' is used to check the operation of the web page.
However, when the laptop is turned off and on, 'yarn start' is not executed in 'terminal'.
I get the error '**bash: yarn: command not found**'. In npm and node, the 'command not found' error appeared at first, but after setting the PATH, it was resolved by running 'npm update' every time the terminal was restarted.
However, 'yarn' is not resolved even if PATH is set. How can I solve this?

Comment: do you use the global tag? `npm install --global yarn` most likely your PC has some type of ephemeral mode, where installations are deleted after each sign out

Comment: @DavidSalomon Yes. I installed using `npm install --global yarn`. But there was a problem, so the same problem occurred even though I reinstalled it four times.